# My react app title doesn't show title and description

Tags: reactjs

I'm using helmet react js 6.1.0 and it's working only if I load the page and stay in the same tab,
but if I reload the page and go to another browser tab the page remains titleless until I revisit that tab again.
and I'm using webpack 5 I'm wondering if it can cause these kinds of bugs.
this is my web app https://avoconsulte.com

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using react-navi with helmet, then you have to import and wrap your Router with HelmetProvider

`npm install --save react-navi-helmet-async`

```
import HelmetProvider from 'react-navi-helmet-async'

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelmetProvider>
    <Router routes={routes}>
      ...
    </Router>
  </HelmetProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Check out detailed discription on react-navi documentation:
https://frontarm.com/navi/en/guides/setting-head-meta-title/#the-react-helmet-and-react-helmet-async-integrations